# Image not loading using AngularJS ng-repeat and ng-src directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

So basically when I was using native html5 i was using five `<img src="">` tags to load five images. When i wanted to use AngularJS i thought of iterating a `div` five times through `ng-repeat` and using `ng-src=""` get the image whose source path is stored in an array in the controller. But some how im always getting this error `GET file:///home/sanad/Desktop/drag/x.source net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

This is my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in img">{{x.source}}
    <img ng-id="x.id" ng-src="x.source" >
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
var app=angular.module('d2d',[]);
app.controller('imageCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.img=[
        {id:'table',source:'images/table.jpg'},
        {id:'paper',source:'images/paper.jpg'},
        {id:'computer',source:'images/computer.jpg'},
        {id:'ac',source:'images/ac.jpg'},
        {id:'sofa',source:'images/sofa.jpg'}
    ];
});
```

Comment: Try use <img ng-src="{{x.source}}">

Comment: you might want to set the image with css instead using an image. Angularjs have security policies that might disable ng-src on images inside ng-repeat: `<div data-ng-repeat="i in images"><div style="background:url(imgs/{{i.srcimg}})"></div></div>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 <div  ng-repeat="x in img">
     <img ng-src="{{x.source}}" >
 </div>`
```

I'm not sure about what ng-src does so I did not suggested it in first place.

I also have the feeling that using a directive for doing something that html does well is not a good approach. In fact, it instantiates new scopes, new watches,...

**Edit:**

Using `src="{{param}}"` instead of `ng-src="{{param}}"` could lead the browser to make a call to the url `http:\\yourServer\{{param}}`, which would be invalid. `ng-src` has been created to solve that problem.

Comment: According to the AngularJS API, this is a "buggy way to do it". The correct is to use mixing your answer with the question. `<img ng-src="{{x.source}}"/>`. Ref: [Angular API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: FYI ng-src does not create a new scope or a new watch. A watch is added by virtue of the interpolation ({{}}) in both cases. There is no extra watch from one solution to the other. Also, both solutions do not create additional scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this too

```
<img ng-repeat="x in img" src="{{x}}">
```

it works properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<img ng-repeat="x in img" ng-src="{{x.source}}">
```

If you have just an array of images

```
<img ng-repeat="img in images track by $index" ng-src="{{img}}">
```